# avformat_write_header() doesn't work when writing data to memory instead of file

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libavformat

i want to resample a given input format from memory to memory everything is good so far.

but when trying to get the output header from ffmpeg it doesn't work.

here i allocate the context and pass the write_buffer function pointer so that it doesn't write to a file but instead it will call my function with the required data

```
unsigned char * aviobuffer = (unsigned char *) av_malloc (32768);
AVIOContext * avio = avio_alloc_context (aviobuffer, 32768,1, NULL, NULL, write_buffer, NULL);

AVFormatContext* containerContext;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&containerContext, NULL, "s16le", NULL);
containerContext->pb = avio;
```

here is my write_buffer function

```
std::vector<char>* data;
int write_buffer(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)
{
    std::vector<char> tmp;
    tmp.assign(buf, buf + buf_size);
    data->insert(data->end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    return buf_size;
}
```

now when i call avformat_write_header() it doesn't call my write_buffer() function + it returns 0 which means success.

```
int ret = avformat_write_header(containerContext, NULL);
```

after that i call the appropriate functions to get the data body itself and my write_buffer() get called normally so i am now left with the data body with no header !!

how can i get the output header anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after a lot of debugging that led me to discover the way ffmpeg writes format headers.

long story short, some formats are associated with special functions for writing their headers.

the `"s16le"` format inside ffmpeg is not associated with one. but surprisingly as i stated in the question ffmpeg can write its data body but no header!!
so i searched for a format that is close to what i want and supports writing its header. i found the `"wav"` format, tried it and it worked nicely. fortunately wav's default is s16le which is exactly what i want.

so in conclusion i changed this line of code

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&containerContext, NULL, "s16le", NULL);
```

to

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&containerContext, NULL, "wav", NULL);
```